# Java - Cucumber Tag Exclusion Not Working

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have created a Cucumber runner class, and I am attempting to run a particular subset of tests by including one Cucumber tag and excluding another. I am using Maven as a project manager.

```
package cucumber_runner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/", 
    glue = "stepdefinitions",
    tags = {"@test", "~@homepage"})
public class RunCukesTest {

}
```

The result of running `mvn test` in the project folder, however, is that none of the Cucumber tests are run at all. Once I remove the ~ character from the tags, like so: `tags = {"@test", "@homepage"})`, the tests execute as expected, only considering feature files that have both the @test and @homepage tags. How do I properly exclude the @homepage tag from my tests?

Comment: you could try - tags = "@test and (not @homepage)"

Comment: That... actually worked? Thank you for that, although I would still like to know why the original way isn't functioning.

Comment: Looks like you're using the old syntax. Using `~` for not was deprecated but I guess you missed that version while upgrading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been told in the comments that the syntax I was using was deprecated, so I looked up the new syntax: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags

Leaving this here for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
tags = "@test and @homepage"
```